# Url rewrite rule

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, php, mod-rewrite

How to redirect a page form show.php?id=(15charstring) to show/(15charstring)

I tried like this it is doing reverse means it is redirecting /show/(15chars) to show.php?id=(15chars)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/show/([a-zA-Z0-9]{15})$ http://site.com/show.php?id=$1
```

Second case is i have to redirect to another page if he added &m=true to the url

```
show.php?id=(15chars)&m=true 

html/show.php?id=(15chars).
```

Comment: What Sathya didn't do was to say that this would be better over on Stack Overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=htaccess+rewrite

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^show/([^/]{15})$   show.php?id=$1  [L]
```

Comment: The requested URL /show/4de34rwa7eg70sw was not found on this server